# getting filtered list from collectionview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, observablecollection

Iam using collection view source to filter one of mylist(observable Collection).It works fine and list is filtered on UI.How can I access filtered list in Viewmodel.I want to unit test this code.

```
ICollectionView collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyListCollection);
collectionView.Filter(myPredicate);
```

Comment: Call the PassesFilter method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview.passesfilter.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ICollectionView view = ...
view.Filter = ...

foreach(Foo o in view)
{
    ...
}
```

or

```
var filteredItems = view.Cast<Foo>();
```